# Getting Error while reading input from Console in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, console

I have tried using "readline" but I am getting error like :

You can see I am just trying to read a value from console.

solution.js:5

```
var input_stdin_array = "";
```

var input_currentline = 0;

function readLine() {    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];}

function processData(input) {

```
var M = parseDouble(readLine());

console.log("M : "+M-1);

var T = parseInt(readLine());

var X = parseInt(readLine());

var final_price = M + ((T*12)/100) + ((X*12)/100);

console.log("The final price of the meal is $"+final_price);
```

}

process.stdin.resume();

process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");

_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {

```
_input += input;
```

});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {

processData(_input);

});

```
                 ^
```

ReferenceError: readLine is not defined
    at processData (solution.js:5:22)

```
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (solution.js:20:4)

at emitNone (events.js:72:20)

at ReadStream.emit (events.js:166:7)

at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)

at doNTCallback2 (node.js:452:9)

at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)
```

Comment: There is no global readLine() method.

Comment: Then What is the solution for this? Do you understand my question bro @ E. Sundin

Comment: Now, I am not getting any error but no values are being read. When i print them its printing as  "Undefined"..                                                      what i did is :  wrote these additional lines :                                               var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;                                                                  function readLine() {    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];}

Comment: You are using readLine in a context where it is not defined. If you want more help you should include the code itself. Not just these error.